# Source Solution to heat equation Sense of distribution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

We are given that the source solution to the heat equation, $u_t=\kappa \Delta u$, is given by:
$$
S(x,t)=\left(\frac{1}{4\pi \kappa t}\right)^{n/2} \exp\left[ -\frac{|x|^2}{4\kappa t}\right].
$$

I want to show that:
$$R(x,t;x_0,t_0)=S(x-x_0,t-t_0), \ t>t_0, \ R=0, \ t<t_0, \ x\in\mathbb{R}^n
$$
satisfies
$$
R_t-\kappa \,\Delta R=\delta(x-x_0)\delta(t-t_0).
$$

I believe this is in the sense of distribution.

I know that I can show that $S(x,t)=\delta(x)$ in the sense of distribution, but I am not really sure what to do here.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually if any help could be given for the one dimensional case that would be great. For a reference see Partial Differential Equations an Introduction by Strauss. Chapter 12.